# Filling 2 MA with resolution

Tags: pine-script

Hi I'm trying to plot EMA and SMA with a resolution of W and filling the background between them.
This is my code:

```
study("Support Band", overlay=true, resolution="W")

src = input(close)

ema = input(21, minval=1, title='EMA')
sma = input(20, minval=1, title='SMA')

pema = ema(src, ema)
psma = sma(src, sma)

//fil
emaplot = plot(pema, color=#2ecc71, linewidth=1, title='EMA')
smaplot = plot(psma, color=#f00b0b, linewidth=1, title='SMA')

fill(emaplot, smaplot, color=pema>psma? color.rgb(0, 255, 0, 50):color.rgb(255, 0, 0, 50), editable=true, fillgaps=true)
```

For some reason the background does not fill when viewing Daily but shows when viewing Weekly. I have tried fillgaps but didn't work. Any help appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Morning,

Test on several time frames and works.

```
study(title="StackOverFlow123", shorttitle="StackOverFlow123", overlay=true)

len21 = input(21, minval=1, title="Length")
len20 = input(20, minval=1, title="Length")

res = input(title="Resolution", type=input.string, defval="W")

pema = security(syminfo.tickerid, res, ema(close, len21))
psma = security(syminfo.tickerid, res, sma(close, len20))

emaplot = plot(pema, color=#2ecc71, linewidth=1, title='EMA')
smaplot = plot(psma, color=#f00b0b, linewidth=1, title='SMA')


fill(emaplot, smaplot, color=pema>psma? color.rgb(0, 255, 0, 50):color.rgb(255, 0, 0, 50), editable=true, fillgaps=true)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, added "barmerge.gaps_on" to smooth it out.